# How to find out which app locks a given USB storage device?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Windows tell me what is using my USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/87364/can-windows-tell-me-what-is-using-my-usb-drive)

I'd like to unplug my USB mass storage device, but I get the following error message from Windows:

*Windows can't stop your 'XYZ' device because it is in use. Close any programs or windows that might be using the device, and then try again later.*

How can I find out which application locks the device, so I can safely unplug it without having to close all running applications first?

**Note**: I'm working on a Windows Vista system.

Comment: This is a frequently asked question. Can we organise a group beating of Microsoft employees until they add this function to their operating system?