# How can I find out what's blocking my device? (Sysinternals Process Explorer didn't help)

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, mount, esata

I have an eSATA docking station like the one in this picture:

[image]

Every now and then, when I try to eject my drive, Windows complains with the following message:

[image]

### Things I tried:

1. I followed the instructions in this thread:
   [Can Windows tell me what is using my USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/87364/can-windows-tell-me-what-is-using-my-usb-drive) and I have [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) installed, but when I search for the drive letter (`F:\` in my case) nothing pops up.
2. Following Oliver Salzburg's suggestion I run `mountvol` on `cmd` and got the unique drive identifier that widnows reports is associated with `F:\`. I then searched for any handles referring to this identifier in [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) but again nothing popped up.
3. Following Alan's suggestion I tried [Sysinternals handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655), ahd this is what I got:

> Handle v3.46 Copyright (C) 1997-2011 Mark Russinovich Sysinternals -
>   www.sysinternals.com
>
> svchost.exe        pid: 1020   type: File           594: F:
>
> svchost.exe        pid: 1020   type: File           5C4:
>   F:\$Extend\$ObjId
>
> svchost.exe        pid: 1020   type: File           604: F:\System
>   Volume Information\tracking.log

I can see that svchost is blocking my process, which technically answers my question. Now, would anybody mind helping me figure out how, knowing this, I can unblock the device?

Comment: Maybe it's not being accessed through the drive letter, but through the unique device identifier. Use `mountvol` to determine it.

Comment: eSATA is not USB also.

Comment: Try Handle -c 1020

Comment: Using Process Explorer you can easily determine what services are run by that service host by simply hovering with your mouse over the process with that PID (1020).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the command line [**Handle** utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655), also from SysInternals.

At the prompt, issue:

```
handle f:
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use "Run as administrator" when running Process Explorer.  This will allow it to show additional things (like System and svchost.exe) that have open handles to the drive.