# How to safely remove a USB drive when “Windows can't stop your 'Generic volume' device because a program is still using it.”?

Tags: usb

Please guys help me i really don't know how to eject my Flash Drive safely when it appears How to safely remove a USB drive when “Windows can't stop your 'Generic volume' device because a program is still using it.”? please how tell me im really worried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Windows tell me what is using my USB drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/87364/can-windows-tell-me-what-is-using-my-usb-drive)

Answer (score -1):

If you are not actively using any files on that drive (eg. a file is open in Word) then chances are it's something internal happening, such as

- Antivirus scan
- Windows search indexing
- etc

In these case I prefer waiting a bit - 5 (10 max) min and the problem resolves itself. If it doesn't, or you can't wait then see **P. Ktinos**'s answer.

However, when this happens to me I wait and if it doesn't fix then I simply pull out the usb drive - haven't had anything broken so far. **EDIT**: if you do this, you must be 100% sure that there is no writing going or you can brick your device

Comment: "I simply pull out the usb drive" that is a great way to lose data and perhaps the whole USB stick.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yeah, my bad, added a warning