Why I never get to eject my USB drive properly?
Since when USB drives started to be a common thing, I never could eject any USB drive properly. When I try to eject using the 'correct way' by clicking on 'eject' on the Windows taskbar, I always get the error below. No matter what USB drive is, brand, size, the only way I get to eject it is by ignoring this error message.
Is there a way to know WHAT APP or process is using the drive at the moment, to try to find out what is happening?


Does this answer your question? Find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows

Also https://superuser.com/questions/1395207/safely-removing-usb-gets-windows-cant-stop-your-device-because-a-program-is-st

Note: Sometimes the Windows Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media icon does not appear, or does nothing when used. Particularly to prevent damage to the file system of external HDD, I use a third-party tool such as HotSwap, http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm, or an alternative. However, that apparently is not the issue you have.

Microsoft made a change to Windows over a decade ago where ejecting a removable disk is likely not required in 99% of the cases.

I've been in similar status, windows 7, and found https://safelyremove.com/index.htm a useful add-in, problem solved for me, perhaps for you?

https://superuser.com/questions/87364/can-windows-tell-me-what-is-using-my-usb-drive

Does this answer your question? Can Windows tell me what is using my USB drive?

Event Viewer


Open Event Viewer, for example in any of the following ways:

right click on the Start button → Event Viewer
or left click on the Start button → start typing "Event Viewer" → Enter


in the Event Viewer, go to Windows Logs → System
Select recent events with the event ID 225
Under the list of events, the path and process ID of the culprit will be shown

source
After finding out what's happening, you might want to solve the problem:

If the culprit is The application System with process id 4, proceed as described here.
Otherwise, close the culprit directly or via the Task Manager.


Thats odd, the culprit was Task Manager ! Once i close it, i could eject my usb . But why ?

Resource Monitor
You can find open file handles and disk activity in the Resource Monitor:

Start the Resource Monitor (for example Win+R → resmon → OK)
To view open file handles: CPU tab → tick the check box on the upper left to select all processes → in the Associated Handles pane, type the drive letter in question such as A:\ and click on the ⌄ button to show the list.
To view disk activity: Disk tab → in the Disk Activity pane, click on the File column header to sort by path, and scroll to the disk letter in question.

