# How to unmount a blocked usb external HDD in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive, unmount, file-unlocking

I have an external HDD connected to my PC using Windows 10, which is used to a daily backup using Acronis True Image 2019.

Many times after the backup is finished, I can't dismount it.

Even removing some Acronis processes o Windows task manager, the HDD is still blocked.

In this case, just restarting windows to release the device and unmount it.

I'd like to know if there is any way to identify and close all processes/services that are blocking this external USB HDD?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Windows tell me what is using my USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/87364/can-windows-tell-me-what-is-using-my-usb-drive)

Comment: You might try LockHunter. https://lockhunter.com/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, based on your tip, I searched a more specific solution: https://safelyremove.com/index.htm which solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @RogérioDec If the external HDD LED is still flashing, perhaps you have Acronis set to verify the backup after it's done the actual backup.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, no, it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the @DrMoishePippik comment above, I searched a more specific solution: https://safelyremove.com/index.htm

That was the unique software I found to correctly unmount blocked USB devices.