# Explorer.exe and System prevent the ejection of an external hard drive

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, eject

I have an external hard drive that I could not eject despite all programs being closed.

I followed the instructions explained in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1102080/1697187) to check which process was preventing the drive from being ejected.

I found two entries in the log:

- `The application \Device\HarddiskVolume5\Windows\explorer.exe with process id 21776 stopped the removal or ejection for the device USB\VID_0480&PID_0901\20211220017702F.`
- `The application System with process id 4 stopped the removal or ejection for the device USB\VID_0480&PID_0901\20211220017702F.`

What should I do? Should I kill `explorer.exe`? What is `System`? Should I kill that too?

Comment: I usually just sign off, wait 30 seconds, sign on and most of the time (90%) the drive can now be ejected.  Best way.

Comment: Try `Ctrl+Alt+Del` to open Task Manager. Scroll to find **Windows Explorer**. Right click and select "Restart" to kill and restart explorer. Wait till Taskbar loads and try to eject. Tell us if this was successful